# LINK : fatal error LNK1000: Internal error during LIB::Search

Tags: c++11, linker-errors

Compiling a c++ project in Visual studio 2019, got this error for 64 bit:
LINK : fatal error LNK1000: Internal error during LIB::Search

Answer (score 2):

There are not many posts about this error in the internet, I tried a few things including setting 'whole program optimization' to false, reboot the computer, clean build.  Later I found in another computer where compilation succeeds with the same code and configuration, that the VS version is higher. Thus I upgrade VS by going to VS->help->check for update, and update VS to 16.11, then the link error is gone. Hope this helps someone with the same issue.